# Graph classification given node-level outputs using global pooling in pytorch

Tags: classification, pooling, graph-neural-network

I have node-level outputs for a graph classification task. Based on [this](https://tkipf.github.io/graph-convolutional-networks/) article on GCN, it seems like I have to introduce a pooling layer to transform my outputs into graph-level outputs, which makes sense. In Pytorch geometric, it seems like there are multiple options for this, under the "Global pooling layer" [here](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/nn.html#module-torch_geometric.nn.glob). How do I choose which one to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with most things, best way to find out is try them all and see what works best. But some things to note are:

1. Probably want to avoid sum-pool unless you know for a fact that your graphs are fixed size, otherwise avg-pool makes a lot more sense.
2. I suspect, but can't say for sure that if your graphs are highly variable in size that avg pool would also work better than max-pool, since you'd expect max gets pushed higher and higher as graph size increases but avg would not.
3. I slightly skeptical about sortpooling, seeing as the ablation study in the paper didn't seem very convincing to me, and I haven't seen sortpooling used much elsewhere (then again I'm not a graph nn expert). Can't hurt to try though.